# How to read JSON file in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net

I have a JSON file:

```
 {
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "HkWO1yuYnLU",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCR5wZcXtOUka8jTA57flzMg",
    "title": "İlyas Yalçıntaş - İçimdeki Duman",
    "categoryId": "10"
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "37266431",
    "likeCount": "122255",
    "dislikeCount": "4472",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "7151"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

and i want to get this info, like this:

```
label1.text = "Rap GOD"  
label2.text = "122255 likes"
```

how do i do it?

Comment: Please read [Ask] and also take the [Tour].  You'll need to deserialize or parse it depending on how much of the info you want

Answer (score 9):

Here's what you can do...

1. Firstly, download the [**JSON Framework**](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)
2. Add the reference to your Project by *Right-clicking* on your *Project* and **Add Reference**
3. Then, Browse `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`*(extract the library which you downloaded in **step 1**)* and add the reference from the **Reference Manager** Window.

[image: Reference Manager]

4. Add this code:

   ```
   Public Class Form1

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      Dim json As String = "{""name"":""Rap God"",""statistics"":{""likeCount"":""122255"",""dislikeCount"":""4472""}}"
      Dim read = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json)
      TextBox1.Text = read.Item("name").ToString
      TextBox2.Text = read.Item("statistics")("likeCount").ToString + " " + " times"
   End Sub  

   End Class
   ```

And, here's the expected output:

[image: Output]

And, I hope this above code helps. Now, you can easily read any *JSON* File using **VB.NET**.

Comment: huge project. Didnt compile out of the box. Can you make a smaller one?

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.IO

Dim bowerjson As String = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bower.json"))
Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(bowerjson)
```

Comment: Hi, your answer might be right but please try to explain your code when posting answers

Comment: i second ali, please add some explanation to your post. for WindowsForms users, http doesnt make any sense.